# Scala - String and Column objects

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here the variable "exprs" is of column type (i.e. `exprs: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(sum(country), sum(value), sum(price)))`.

why does `exprs: _*` runs into error? why should I provide head and tail which as far my understanding is only for string type?

`val resGroupByDF2 = data.groupBy($"country").agg(exprs: _*)` // why does this not work

```
case class (
     country: String,
     value: Double,
     price: Double
  )

  val data = Seq(
    cname("NA", 2, 14),
    cname("EU", 4, 61),
    cname("FE", 5, 1),
  )
    .toDF()

val exprs = data.columns.map(sum(_)) // here it returns exprs: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(sum(country), sum(value), sum(price))

val resGroupByDF2 = data.groupBy($"country").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*) // why just agg(exprs: _*) does not work in select or agg as it is already a column type
```

Comment: split it head and tails.

Comment: @Lamanus can you please elaborate? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because of signature of `agg`.

The signature is `(expr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, exprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`. This expects a column at least and optional var-arg.

Comment: Which specific part do you want me to elaborate?

Comment: In the above example, when I try data.select(exprs: _*), it works. However when I try the same ie .agg(exprs: _*) it does not work. I thought it should work as its if type column. Hence can you provide details as why .agg() not working and why I should provide head/tail to make it work?

Comment: Thats because method signature is different.